# What is the meaning in Python when we add star to a function?

Tags: python

I am stuck at line 196 of this [Github code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py).

```
li.append((1.0, *update_probability_matrix(row, col, a)))
```

I am not able to understand, why is * associated with update_probability_matrix(row, col, a). What is the meaning in Python when we add star to a function?

Comment: The above two articles don't answer my question. I have an asterisk in front of a function. What they have discussed is something else.

Comment: Your function return some value and the * here works on them, see the example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/11318161

Comment: It doesn’t matter what it’s in front of, it matters what it’s inside. You’re right that those aren’t correct exact duplicates, though; this is unpacking inside a tuple literal, not a function call.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448